# How do I make subform row items appear only once in an HTML table in zoho creator snippet pages?

Tags: crm, code-snippets, zoho, zohobooks

[Table Screenshot I need a single row of Engineer with count 2 in head count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Q0z.png)

I have attached a screenshot. Category fields are fetched from a subform rows and rows can contain similar categories. I want to show category only once in this table  with its count in head count. For example Engineer  - 2 and not as it is currently being shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`distinct`](https://www.zoho.com/deluge/help/data-access/aggregate-records/distinct.html) option from Zoho Creator data access task to get the unique list of `Category`. Then use this list to fetch the count of each item.

This also depends on how the subform was included in the main form and whether you are looking to fetch the count per each record of the main form or for all records in the main form.

If the subform was directly created insider the main form, you will have to follow the above method. If the subform was created separately and then embedded into the main form, you can directly apply the `Count` and `Distinct` operations instead of iterating through all values.

Answer (score 0):

Store the Category in the list. in loop check, if the category already exists or not then add into list.